# IBM Connections - can't add opensocial gadget

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt, opensocial

I developed an open social gadget and am trying to display it in Connections. I can't get Connections to even try to load the xml definition file.

I get 
"**Unable to load widget**" in the gadget area in the side column

In JS console the errors read:

**(Usable to retrieve spec for *gadgeturl*. HTTP error 400) while loading widget**

**_WidgetHandleBase - gadget failed to load (*gadgeturl*)**

Here's what I did:

1)
Enabled developer mode and restarted Connections. I used this guide as a reference, allServers attribute is set to true so I'm not using the whitelist.
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/OS_gadget_IC4_final.pdf

2)
Configured the gadget in admin section of Connections.

- Type: Open Social Gadget
- Security: Trusted, Use SSO
- Server Access via Proxy: All Servers
- Display on the Widgets page: True
- Display on the Updates page: True
- Use IBM Connections specific tags: True
- Opened by default: True

3) Added the gadget through the customize link

Again, the gadget url leads to an xml definition file and it is accessible via a browser. Connections never accessed the url based on server logs.

Any idea what I am missing?

Thanks,
Vilem

Comment: are you able to access the gadget url from the system with connections is on?

Comment: also, is whitelisting disabled in the opensocial-config.xml?

Comment: The answer was negative to both questions. When I set it up, the gadget appeared. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Paul Bastide's questions I did these additional steps:

- In opensocial-config.xml I set all whitelistEnabled and urlWhitelistEnabled attributes to false. Setting up just the developer tag attributes like the doc suggested wasn't enough.
- Set up hosts file to allow the connections server to access the gadget url.

For clarity I am using the Greenhouse image.